# pySpark withColumn with two conditions

Tags: python, pyspark, conditional-statements

I want to filter for two conditions: `clean_reference.Output == " "` ***and***  `clean_reference.Primary == "DEFAULT"`. If both conditions apply, then `clean_reference.Output` else `"NI"`

The code below is not accepting my `clean_reference.Output`as my when() value.

```
final_reference = clean_reference.withColumn("Output",f.when(clean_reference.Output == " ")| (clean_reference.Primary == "DEFAULT"), clean_reference.Output).otherwise("NI")
```

```
TypeError: when() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same code, just fixed the braces.

```
final_reference = clean_reference.withColumn(
        "OutputItemNameByValue",
        f.when( 
          (clean_reference.OutputItemNameByValue == " ") | 
          (clean_reference.PrimaryLookupAttributeValue == "TRIANA_DEFAULT"),
          clean_reference.OutputItemNameByValue
        ).otherwise("Not Implemented")
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your cols like **`f.col()`** and value to assign as **`f.lit()`**.

```
final_reference = clean_reference.withColumn("Output",\
                       f.when((f.col("Output") == " ")|                              
                             (f.col("Primary") ==\
                              "DEFAULT"), f.col("Output"))\
                                             .otherwise(f.lit("NI")))
```